# how to render a string which include custom component dynamically in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I get a string which includes custom vue components like below from backend

```
<p>this is an example <custom-component-1 :value="1"/>, string from backend <custom-component-2/></p>
```

**custom-component-1.vue**

```
<template>
    <span>custom-component-1 {{ value }}</span>
</template>
<script>
export default{
    props: [value]
}
</script>
```

**custom-component-2.vue**

```
<template>
    <span>{{ value }} <button @click="value++">+1</button></span>
</template>
<script>
export default{
    data(){
        return {
            value: 1
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to render the string from backend like this (the methods in components can work well)

```
<p>this is an example <span>custom-component-1 1</span>, string from backend <span>1 <button>+1</button></span></p>
```

---

What I tried:

```
<template>
    <div v-html="raw"></div>
</template>
<script>
import CustomComponent1 from '~/components/custom-component-1.vue';
import CustomComponent2 from '~/components/custom-component-2.vue';
export default{
    components: {
        CustomComponent1, CustomComponent2
    },
    data(){
        return {
            raw: ''
        }
    },
    created(){
         axios.get('http://api.example.com').then(({ data }) => {this.raw = data});
         // data = `<p>this is an example <custom-component-1 :value="1"/>, string from backend <custom-component-2/></p>`
    }
}
</script>
```

but this won't render the components inside of the string like what I expect.

So, how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot for anyone help!

Comment: This should help you: `https://forum.vuejs.org/t/add-component-to-dom-programatically/7308`

Comment: What do you get when you console.log data ?

Comment: `v-html` use to render pure HTML text, not a Vue template which needs parsing